# Change image on click by another thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to change image on click to another image.

In my example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Frunky/7kp3xbur/1/) it works

But on my Wordpress site, it doesn't work and I don't know why. Click event doesn't work, but if I add alert('1')(for example) it works only one time.

```
jQuery('.thumbnails img').click(function() {
    var attr = jQuery(this).attr('src');
    var src = jQuery('.main-image img').attr('src');
    jQuery('.main-image img').attr('src', attr);
    jQuery(this).attr('src', src);
});

<div class="images">
  <div class="main-image">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails columns-3" style="display: block;">
    <img width="184" height="123" src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail size-shop_thumbnail">
  </div>
</div>
```

Where's my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: wrap your code inside `jQuery(document).ready(function(){..})` or put it into footer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm tried it but without any luck(

Comment: did you get any error in console? check you browser console for error

Comment: No errors, also  I'm tried jQuery('.thumbnails img').click(function() { console.log('Clicked); }); and it's not working too. but image has z-index: 99999999

Comment: Thanks, man! You was right, I'm removed opacity and it's works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1.*** Either wrap you code inside `jQuery(document).ready(function(){..})` like below:-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.thumbnails img').click(function() {
    var attr = jQuery(this).attr('src');
    var src = jQuery('.main-image img').attr('src');
    jQuery('.main-image img').attr('src', attr);
    jQuery(this).attr('src', src);
  });
});
```

Or put your code into footer of you WordPress.

***2.*** Also by looking you website i saw that you `main-image` parent div have style `opacity:1`.remove that and it will start work (due to `opacity` click is not working).

***Note:-*** Make sure that jQuery library is added.

Comment: @Frunky  you have opacity in your parent div.remove it and it will work

Comment: Thanks again! It works, You was right! The problem was in opacity! If You can, please, update the answer)

Answer (score 1):

User SetTimeOut may be this would help you.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('.thumbnails img').click(function() {
    var attr = jQuery(this).attr('src');
    var src = jQuery('.main-image img').attr('src');
    jQuery('.main-image img').attr('src', attr);
    jQuery(this).attr('src', src);
  });},0)
});
```